# Open local Raster Tiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, tiles, qgis-2

I have a local directory with a **Raster Tile**, downloaded with SAS Planet (I know about the license issues, its just a personal test).

In **Global Mapper** I can load it directly from the directory using:
*file:///D:....\z%z\%y\%x.jpg*

My question is, can I do the same in QGIS using local files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the same in QGIS with the TileLayer plugin. It needs a **TAB** delimited file with the path to your tiles. In the settings of the plugin, you have to point to the folder where the file is. An example line of mine:

```
Topo    Topo    file:///F:/Tiles/Topo/{z}/{x}/{y}.png   1   0   16  -180    -85.0   180.0   85.0
```

I'm not sure if the plugin is limited to png files; I have no jpg tiles.

Another choice is a local apache server, which lets you access the tiles via localhost. I used MS4W to put up that server, but OSGEO4W (32bit only) works as well.

Comment: Works for JPG tiles too.

Answer (score 1):

Although **AndreJ** solution works fine, I found and easier way to manage local tiles in QGIS using MBTiles 1.2 (**SQLite**) format. *SAS Planet* has an option to export the downloaded tiles to this format.